# Find common worrd between to string and join it in new string

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am having strings :

```
str1 = "A born in 1980"
str2 = "B born in 1980"
str3 = "C born in 1988"
```

I have to form string as :

```
str 4 = "A and B are born in 1980 and C born in 1988"
```

How to convert it ?

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: How flexible do you need the solution to be? I think this is too broad!

Comment: is there any lodash function to do this?
I am happy if i will get solution in 2-3 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easier one liner solutioh using lodash

```js
var inputs = ["A born in 1980", "B born in 1980", "C born in 1988"];
var res = _(inputs).groupBy(str=>_.words(str)[3]).map((words, year)=>words.map(w=>w[0]).join(' and ') + (words.length > 1 ? ' are ' : ' ') + 'born in ' + year).value().join(' and ')

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` first to get object for each year as a key and then again to create string.

```js
let str1 = "A born in 1980",
  str2 = "B born in 1980",
  str3 = "C born in 1988"

let obj = [str1, str2, str3].reduce(function(r, e) {
  let arr = e.split(' '), n = arr.shift(), y = arr.pop();
  if (!r[y]) r[y] = n;
  else r[y] = [].concat(r[y], n);
  return r;
}, {})

let r = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, k) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj[k])) {
    r += (r.length ? ' ' : '') + obj[k].join(' and ') + ' are born in ' + k;
  } else {
    r += ' and ' + obj[k] + ' is born in ' + k
  }
  return r;
}, '')

console.log(r)
```